# Is there any possible to get server time in angular

Tags: angular

Local system time and date may be wrong. Hence I want server time and date in my Angular. Is there any possible?? if possible guide me..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you want to use data from the server you have to integrate backend endpoint (REST API) into your Angular app. If you want to get more information please be more specific in asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is quite straightforward. You just create an API on the backend that returns the current server time when requested. You can create a function called `getCurrentServerTime()` in your `utility.service.ts` (if you have one).

```
getCurrentServerTime(): Observable<any> {
  let apiURL = 'https://yoursite.com/api/getCurrentServerTime';
  return this.http.get(apiURL);
}
```

And then you can access this in any component using Dependency Injection. You can inject this service in the constructor of your component.

```
constructor(private utilityService: UtilityService) { }

this.utilityService.getCurrentServerTime().subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.currentServerTime = data.currentServerTime;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can expose an endpoint `/now` which return the date from your server. You can do a http call to this endpoint to ask for date whenever necessary.

Comment: Sunitha, if your server has the "/now" endpoint, it doesn't mean his server has the same endpoint. I would suggest you remove your answer

Comment: His answer is correct. He suggested he creates an endpoint on his server, not use existing.